# Switch realisation for power converter

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, inverter

[image: Question]

I am having trouble understanding this question. From what I derived all four switches seem to have +ve current and +ve voltage for each switching cycle.

Apparently, SW1 and SW2 are meant to be current bidirectional (which is where I am confused), while SW3 and SW4 are intended to be regular transistor single quadrant switches, making sense.

I'm unsure if I'm missing something fundamental in understanding this question.

Comment: Conventional current flows downwards through all four switches.

Answer (score 1):

What is shown can be thought of as an H-bridge driver, using PWM control to synthesize a sine wave at the output.

It’s very similar, topology-wise, to a Class-D audio amplifier. In this case it’s outputting one frequency only: the line cycle rate. The inductors form integrators / low pass filters to block the PWM switching noise.

Their system exploits the symmetry of the AC waveform: it uses the switches SW3 and SW4 merely to switch polarity, while SW1 and SW2 do the heavy lifting of making the PWM sine.

So the whole system will have some feedback to ensure that not only is the inverter locked to the line properly, but also that the flow of power is from Vbus to the AC line.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage on the capacitor has a fixed polarity. We want the inverter to inject power from the solar panel into the grid, so Power must flow in the direction of the arrow:

[image]

This sets the direction of current, which has to flow according to the "i" arrow. So, indeed, current in all switches flows top to bottom in this schematic.

Semiconductor switches will be either IGBTs or FETs (silicon, SiC or GaN) and all of these work with one polarity of voltage, but not necessarily current. FETs can conduct in both directions when on, but they can only block when the polarity will not turn the body diode on. IGBTs need an antiparallel diode to protect against reverse biasing. So the switches in the H-bridge are only controllable when current flows top-to-bottom and voltage across them is "positive on top" on the schematic. Otherwise the diodes conduct.

At power-up when it is connected to the grid, these diodes will act like a rectifier and charge the capacitor to peak grid voltage. When solar power is available, the DC-DC boost will charge this cap above peak grid voltage, so the diodes across the switches don't act as rectifiers anymore.

When the inverter is working, the inverter H-bridge is unidirectional, it does not act as a controlled rectifier allowing power to flow from the grid into the inverter. Inverters that use a battery use this controlled rectifier mode as power factor correction to charge the battery from the grid when needed, but this is not the case with this inverter.

Anyway, if the switches are ideal, to inject power into the grid, we must add the grid impedance Z on the schematic. Then, in complex notation,  current from the inverter to the grid is (Vs(t)-Vac(t))/(Z+2*ZL) with ZL the impedance of the inductors.

If the H-bridge is modulated with PWM such that Vs(t) is a chopped sinewave of same frequency and phase than the grid, and amplitude slightly higher than the grid, then the inverter behaves as an AC sine source and injects power into the grid, which is the goal.

To reduce switching losses, SW3-4 are switched at 50Hz, while SW1-2 do the PWM.

So I would recommend first picking a 0V voltage reference: the negative side of the capacitor should be the most practical.

[image]

Consider the cap is charged to 340V. Then, consider one positive half-cycle of Vac, so Vac goes from 0V to 340V back to 0V. To have proper voltage polarity across all switches, we need both VA and VB between 0V and 340V, so SW3 has to be on, setting VA to 340V, and B swings according to 340V-Vac. Now you can plot the answer to the question, then do it again when Vac polarity revereses and SW4 is on instead of SW3.